# MySQL index performance

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-8.0

I'm running a relatively simply query against a very large DB (~2B records) which, even with indexes, is taking a very long time (currently several minutes and running).

The script relies on two tables (**rd** and **prices**).  Running the query with the below script runs in ~5 seconds, but when I included the commented out clause (as I'd ultimately like a timeseries) performance deteriorates. As I already have indexes on the columns used, I'm not sure how to speed this up further.  Sample data, query and indexes are included below.

**rd**

```
datadate, sedol, ticker, name, q, year, reportDate
2020-05-29, 2198163, CSCO, Cisco Systems Inc, 5901, 2018, 2018-02-14
2020-05-29, 2198163, CSCO, Cisco Systems Inc, 5902, 2018, 2018-05-16
2020-05-29, 2198163, CSCO, Cisco Systems Inc, 5903, 2018, 2018-08-15
2020-05-29, 2198163, CSCO, Cisco Systems Inc, 5904, 2018, 2018-11-14
2020-05-29, 2198163, CSCO, Cisco Systems Inc, 5901, 2019, 2019-02-13
2020-05-29, 2198163, CSCO, Cisco Systems Inc, 5902, 2019, 2019-05-15
2020-05-29, 2198163, CSCO, Cisco Systems Inc, 5903, 2019, 2019-08-14
2020-05-29, 2198163, CSCO, Cisco Systems Inc, 5904, 2019, 2019-11-13
2020-05-29, 2198163, CSCO, Cisco Systems Inc, 5901, 2020, 2020-02-12
```

**prices**

```
dataDate, ticker, optionSymbol, expDate, type, price, strike, last, bid, ask, volume, OI, IV, delta, gamma, theta, vega, aka
2002-02-08, CSCO, CYQ020216C00007500, 2002-02-16, call, 16.76, 7.5, 9.8, 9.2, 9.3, 0, 444, 0.7553, 1, 0, -0.1439, 0, CYQBU
2002-02-08, CSCO, CYQ020216P00007500, 2002-02-16, put, 16.76, 7.5, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 1.4853, 0, 0.0001, -0.0157, 0.0004, CYQNU
2002-02-08, CSCO, CYQ020216C00010000, 2002-02-16, call, 16.76, 10, 6.7, 6.7, 6.8, 20, 372, 0.7553, 1, 0, -0.192, 0, CYQBB
2002-02-08, CSCO, CYQ020216P00010000, 2002-02-16, put, 16.76, 10, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 1.4853, -0.0052, 0.0043, -1.3207, 0.0358, CYQNB
2002-02-08, CSCO, CYQ020216C00012500, 2002-02-16, call, 16.76, 12.5, 4, 4.2, 4.3, 11, 159, 0.7553, 0.9974, 0.0045, -0.5961, 0.019, CYQBV
2002-02-08, CSCO, CYQ020216P00012500, 2002-02-16, put, 16.76, 12.5, 0.05, 0, 0.05, 2, 311, 1.4853, -0.0668, 0.0367, -11.3483, 0.3077, CYQNV
2002-02-08, CSCO, CYQ020216C00015000, 2002-02-16, call, 16.76, 15, 1.9, 1.85, 1.95, 1577, 3887, 0.7553, 0.8629, 0.1223, -10.0396, 0.5213, CYQBC
2002-02-08, CSCO, CYQ020216P00015000, 2002-02-16, put, 16.76, 15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.15, 2595, 43062, 0.6816, -0.1149, 0.1198, -7.7802, 0.461, CYQNC
2002-02-08, CSCO, CYQ020216C00017500, 2002-02-16, call, 16.76, 17.5, 0.3, 0.25, 0.3, 9144, 32613, 0.5865, 0.3179, 0.256, -12.4631, 0.8472, CYQBW
2002-02-08, CSCO, CYQ020216P00017500, 2002-02-16, put, 16.76, 17.5, 0.95, 0.95, 1.1, 12218, 54357, 0.6048, -0.676, 0.2502, -12.6152, 0.8539, CYQNW
```

**Query**

```
SELECT rd.reportDate, o.*
FROM op.prices o
JOIN (
    SELECT *
        , CASE WHEN dayofweek(date_add(rd.reportDate, INTERVAL -21 DAY)) = 1 
               THEN date_add(rd.reportDate, INTERVAL -23 DAY)
               WHEN dayofweek(date_add(rd.reportDate, INTERVAL -21 DAY)) = 7 
               THEN date_add(rd.reportDate, INTERVAL -22 DAY)
               ELSE date_add(rd.reportDate, INTERVAL -21 DAY) 
          END as rdadj 
    FROM eq.rd 
    WHERE ticker = 'CSCO' 
      AND reportDate > '2018-01-01'
) r
    ON r.ticker = o.ticker
    AND o.strike = 45
WHERE r.reportDate between date_add(o.expDate, INTERVAL -6 MONTH) AND o.expDate
  AND o.dataDate = rdadj  #and o.dataDate >= rdadj
  AND r.reportDate > '2018-01-01' 
ORDER BY o.expDate, o.dataDate
```

**Indexes**

[image]

**Create Table**

```
    | rd    | CREATE TABLE `rd` (
      `datadate` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `sedol` text,
      `ticker` text,
      `name` text,
      `q` int DEFAULT NULL,
      `year` int DEFAULT NULL,
      `reportDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
      KEY `reportDate` (`reportDate`,`ticker`(255),`year`,`q`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci 

| prices | CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `dataDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ticker` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `optionSymbol` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `expDate` date NOT NULL,
  `type` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `strike` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `last` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `bid` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `ask` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `OI` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `IV` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `delta` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `gamma` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `theta` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `vega` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `aka` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `dataDate` (`dataDate`,`ticker`,`expDate`,`type`),
  KEY `optionSymbol` (`optionSymbol`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

**Explain**

```
mysql> explain select rd.reportDate, op.*
    ->             from op.prices op 
    ->             inner join (select *
    ->                                 , CASE WHEN dayofweek(date_add(rd.reportDate, INTERVAL -21 DAY)) = 1 THEN date_add(rd.reportDate, INTERVAL -23 DAY)
    ->                                         WHEN dayofweek(date_add(rd.reportDate, INTERVAL -21 DAY)) = 7 THEN date_add(rd.reportDate, INTERVAL -22 DAY)
    ->                                         ELSE date_add(rd.reportDate, INTERVAL -21 DAY) 
    ->                                         END as rdadj 
    ->                                         from eq.rd where ticker = 'CSCO' and reportDate > '2018-01-01') rd
    ->             on rd.ticker = op.ticker
    ->             and op.strike = 45
    ->             where rd.reportDate between date_add(op.expDate, INTERVAL -6 MONTH) and op.expDate
    ->             and op.dataDate > rdadj  #and op.dataDate >= rdadj
    ->             and rd.reportDate > '2018-01-01' order by op.expDate, op.dataDate;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows       | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rd    | NULL       | range | reportDate    | reportDate | 4       | NULL |      47538 |    10.00 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | op    | NULL       | ALL   | dataDate      | NULL       | NULL    | NULL | 2014263835 |     0.04 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)                      |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: I can't tell which table `expDate` is in.  Please qualify all column names when `JOINing`.  And also give `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; it's more thorough than that screenshot.  And `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can see how the Optimizer is currently performing the query.

Comment: @RickJames, updated.

Comment: nits: the `dayofweek` for `reportDate` 21 days ago is teh same as `reportDate`. Strike is a `double` but your criteria is `strike = 45`. This may miss due to precision.  With a `=` compatible type, strike should probably be the first index element on `op`. On `rd` what are the real sizes of the `text` fields in this table? If they can be small varchars that would be be good. In the index `reportDate`, `ticker` should be first (or at least a portion of it >= 4 characters).

Comment: @danblack, thanks, fair points.  I'd actually included the `dayofweek` logic to accommodate a lookback 2 days prior, modified for this Q.  I included `strike` as type double by default but they'll always be integers or half integers.  Re the `reportDate` index, not sure I follow.  I included `reportDate` first since it'll be the item I query on most.  Perhaps to your point, `ticker` won't ever exceed 10 chars, but included the 255 char ref as a default.  Wasn't aware of any impact to that.

Answer (score 3):

Some hints:

- `r.*` is pulling out lots of columns, yet only 2(?) are needed:  reportDate and ticket.  It is better (by a little or by a lot) to fetch only what you need.
- <strike>`rd` refers to a table and to a subquery.  That makes it very difficult for me to read.  Please change.  Ditto for `op` being a database and an alias.</strike>
- Don't use `TEXT` when the value cannot be very long.  (There are multiple reasons -- some minor, some major.)
- Don't use prefix indexing such as `KEY ... ticker(255)`, especially when `ticker` seems to be limited to 8 characters.  This can have a big impact in your quer.
- Have an explicit `PRIMARY KEY` on each table.
- If `year` is part of `reportDate` or `dataDate`, it may be counterproductive to have it as a separate column.  (Also, there is a `YEAR` datatype.)
- If it is possible to "summarize" the day's data each night, that would speed up queries a lot.
- ```
      and op.dataDate > rdadj
     #and op.dataDate >= rdadj   -- Is this the commented out part?
  ```

Are you saying that changing > to >= causes a significant slowdown?

- Indexes:

  ```
    rd:  index(ticker, reportDate)  -- in this order!  and not TEXT!
    prices:  INDEX(strike, expDate, dataDate)   -- in this  order
  ```
- It is usually inefficient to start an index with a date that is used in a "range".
- A minor simplification, assuming "21 days" is always a multiple of 7:
- ```
      dayofweek(date_add(rd.reportDate, INTERVAL -21 DAY))   
     -->
      dayofweek(rd.reportDate)
  ```
- Sargeable...

  ```
     WHERE r.reportDate between date_add(o.expDate, INTERVAL -6 MONTH)
                                     AND o.expDate
    -->
     WHERE o.expDate >= r.reportDate
       AND o.expDate <= r.reportDate + INTERVAL 6 MONTH
  ```
- This may help significantly.

  ```
    INDEX(ticker, strike,   -- in either order,
          expDate, dataDate)  -- then these, in this order
  ```
- The *outer* `AND r.reportDate > '2018-01-01'` seems to be redundant.
- In picking a `PRIMARY KEY`, is there a combination of columns that is unique?  And does it include `ticker`?  And are you I/O-bound?  If yes to all those, be sure to have `ticker` first; this will make any query based on *single* ticker run much faster.  This is because of the I/O savings by having all the CSCO rows "clustered" together.  (Let me know what combo would work; I'll probably have an opinion of how to order the rest.)  Caveat:  Adding a PK is *much* more invasive than adding a secondary index; it will rebuild the entire multi-billion-row table, and probably block any activity during the `ALTER`.
- The table is about 800GB, correct?  How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Was the table built with `innodb_file_per_table=ON`?  How much spare disk space do you have?
- `DOUBLE` takes 8 bytes; `FLOAT` takes 4 bytes.  Some of those metrics could probably be put into `FLOAT`, thereby saving 8GB per column changed.  (Again, this needs a costly table rebuild.  But it could be combined with the `ADD PRIMARY KEY(...)`.)
- Suggest looking carefully at each column to see if it can be shrunk or eliminated or *easily* recomputed when fetched.

Comment: it would be better to add ticker to index on prices table too - INDEX(strike, ticker, expDate, dataDate) because of join conditions. Also it may has a sense to try to swap order on expDate and dataDate in it (it depends on actual data distribution)

Comment: @RickJames, changing from = to >= causes significant slowdown.  = returns in ~5 secs.

Comment: Thanks, Rick.  It took ~week to create the indexes previously,,,are you aware of any way to modify an existing index (to move `dataDate` back in order) versus creating a new one?

Comment: @Nikita - Yes, _if_ the derived table is performed first.  If not then `ticker` in that position gets in the way of `WHERE`.

Comment: @Nikita - No.  The order of columns in an index is _not_ dependent on distribution.  Indexes are used from left to right -- _this_ controls which needs to come before versus after.

Comment: I meant depending on distribution different order may be better

Comment: @Chris - Oh, you changed from `>` to `=`.  Perhaps a typo in your _original_ posting?  I'll look at it again.

Comment: @Chris - An `INDEX` is a BTree.  It can only be completely built (or rebuilt) when there is a change in the columns.  This is because the order of the entries changes.   Ver 8.0?  Then you can `ADD INDEX` without 'much' impact on the running system.  (In which case, does it matter if it takes a week?)  Do you have a test platform with, say, 1% of the data?

Comment: @RickJames, yes, imagine I forgot to update before posting.  The rapid return occurs with `=` (as currently referenced) though.  Wondering if you have thoughts about whether partitioning the table could be useful here as well.

Comment: @Chris - In order to consider partitioning, give me a feel for the data...  I see one test covering 8 months; another covering about 3 weeks.  How old does the data go?  What ranges are typically used?  Is expDate in the future?  Etc.

Comment: @RickJames, `dataDate` ranges about ~20 years (2000 through present).  Ranges would typically be similar to what I used above, mostly because it takes too long to run longer periods.  Ideally I'd be able to pull data back 10 years or more, but the above ranges would be a good start.  `expDate` is the future relative to `dataDate`, but as the data is historical, many `expDate` are in the past now.

Comment: For what it's worth, it would be more usedul to partition on `ticker ` (eg, A-C, D-F, etc) than any date if it were possible

Comment: @Chris - Lots more tips added.

Comment: @Chris - Given that you have a useful index (preferably the PK) _starting_ with `ticker`, no.  Partitioning is _usually_ no better than such an index.  More on partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: @Chris - Re `=` vs `>=` -- Do `EXPLAIN` for each.  You will probably see a radical difference.  If you are still curious about the "why", let me see both explains; I may be able to point it out.  As I discuss [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql), `=` is much easier to optimize than a range.

Comment: @RickJames, like night and day re the `EXPLAIN`.  Adding an index to `eq.rd` at the moment, will updated above with responses to your other comments.